# what's the purpose of calling TypeBuilder.CreateType()

Tags: c#, .net, dynamic-assemblies

I have difficulty in understanding in creating a dynamic assembly, below is some code:

```
public static void CreateMyAsm(AppDomain curAppDomain)
{
   AssemblyName assemblyName = new AssemblyName();
   assemblyName.Name = "MyAssembly";
   assemblyName.Version = new Version("1.0.0.0");
   AssemblyBuilder assembly = curAppDomain.DefineDynamicAssembly(assemblyName, AssemblyBuilderAccess.Save);
   ModuleBuilder module =
   assembly.DefineDynamicModule("zMyAssembly", "zMyAssembly.dll");
   TypeBuilder helloWorldClass = module.DefineType("zMyAssembly.HelloWorld", TypeAttributes.Public);

  /*
   ...configure ConstructorBuilder, FieldBuilder, MethodBuilder  etc with ILGenerator.Emit() here

  ConstructorBuilder constructor = helloWorldClass.DefineConstructor(MethodAttributes.Public, CallingConventions.Standard, constructorArgs);
  ILGenerator constructorIL = constructor.GetILGenerator();
  ...
  FieldBuilder msgField = helloWorldClass.DefineField("theMessage", Type.GetType("System.String"),FieldAttributes.Private);
  constructorIL.Emit(OpCodes.Stfld, msgField);
  */  
   helloWorldClass.CreateType();
   assembly.Save("MyAssembly.dll");
}
```

so my question is, why do we need to call `helloWorldClass.CreateType();`, which creates a type?

Because we normailly get a Type in the main method as:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
   ...
   Type t = Type.GetType("MyAssembly.HelloWorld, MyAssembly");
   ...
}
```

so we can get the type dynamically?

EDIT:
someone says **Type.GetType returns existing metadata. AssemblyBuilder.CreateType introduces new metadata.**

so all the `TypeBuilder.DefineMethod`, `TypeBuilder.DefineField`, `TypeBuilder.DefineConstructor` etc don't 'introduce' metadata? shouldn't it be more sensible that calling `TypeBuilder.DefineXXX` automatically 'write' or 'introduce' metadata on the go, so  AssemblyBuilder.CreateType() is not needed anymore?

Comment: `Type.GetType` returns existing metadata. `AssemblyBuilder.CreateType` introduces new metadata.

Comment: @thehennyy   so all the `TypeBuilder.DefineMethod`, `TypeBuilder.DefineField`,  `TypeBuilder.DefineConstructor` etc don't 'introduce' metadata? shouldn't it be more sensible that calling `TypeBuilder.DefineXXX` automatically 'write' or 'introduce' metadata on the go, so  AssemblyBuilder.CreateType is not needed anymore?

Comment: TypeBuilder is a factory, normally, factories only have one `Create` method that finishes the object being built, allowing no further modifications